# Javascript pause sound when image is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, button, playback

I'm using code that plays sound whn image is loaded (i'm using this as a play button on music player). But I have a problem, you can't stop sound when image is clicked (play button). So, do you know how can I make on this code, so sound pause when image is clicked.

My code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  //Create new function that will update the image source on click.
  function updateImage(el, soundfile) {
      //Determine if music is playing or paused then adjust image 
  source accordingly.
      if(soundfile.mp3.paused) {
          el.src = 

      "imageurl.com";
      } else {
          el.src = "secondimageurl.com";
      }
  };

  function playSound(el,soundfile) {
      if (el.mp3) {
          if(el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.play();
          else el.mp3.pause();
      } else {
          el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
          el.mp3.play();
      }
      //Call new function made whenever the sound is toggled.
      updateImage(document.getElementById("Bottom-1"), el);
  };
   </script>
 <body onload="playSound(this, 'soundsource.mp3');">

 <img src="buttonimage.html" name="Bottom-1" width="50" height="45" 
 border="0" id="Bottom-1"/>
</span>
</body>
```

Comment: You can use the logic within `if` condition and statement at `playSound` function. `function playPause(el) {if (el.mp3) {
          if(el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.play();
          else el.mp3.pause();
      }` and pass `document.body` to the function `playPause(document.body)`

Answer (score 0):

Use [SoundPlayer.js](https://github.com/GustavGenberg/handy-front-end/#soundplayerjs).

```
// Initialize
const player = new SoundPlayer();

// Load the sound
const sound = player.load('Sound.mp3');

// Play the sound
sound.play();

// load & play in one line
const sound = player.load('Sound.mp3').play();
```

And bind the image onclick event

```
image.onclick = function () {

    sound[ sound.isPlaying ? 'pause' : 'play' ]();
    image.src = sound.isPlaying ? 'isPlaying.jpg' : 'isPaused.jpg';

}
```

Full fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/GustavGenberg/dxgph924/